# Unable to get the content of Amazon S3 file and edit that file with python and boto3

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to get the data from a file in Amazon S3, manipulate the content and then save it to another bucket.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3

print('Loading function')


s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_name)
    file_content = s3_object['Body'].read()
    
    initial_data = json.load(file_content)
    # some file manipulation comes here
    
    
    data=json.dumps(initial_data, ensure_ascii=False)
    s3.put_object(Bucket="new bucket name", Body=data, Key=file_name)
```

error message leads me to think that this has something to do with encoding:

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 25, in lambda_handler\n    data_initlal = json.load(file_content)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py\", line 293, in load\n    return loads(fp.read(),\n"
  ]
}
```

Additionally, if I remove the following line from my code:

```
initial_data = json.load(file_content)
```

I get the error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 29, in lambda_handler\n    data=json.dumps(file_content, ensure_ascii=False)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py\", line 234, in dumps\n    return cls(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py\", line 199, in encode\n    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py\", line 257, in iterencode\n    return _iterencode(o, 0)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py\", line 179, in default\n    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '\n"
  ]
}
```

The file that I am trying to edit is a json format and the output should also be json.

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
initial_data = json.load(file_content)
```

Should be:

```
initial_data = json.loads(file_content)
```

Alternatively, replace these two lines:

```py
file_content = s3_object['Body'].read()
    
initial_data = json.load(file_content)
```

with:

```py
initial_data = json.load(s3_object['Body'])
```

The difference is `json.load()` vs `json.loads()`.

Comment: thanks, John, that worked. I will read more about json.load() vs json.loads(). :)

Answer (score 0):

The file_content that you are trying to read is utf-8 encoded. You need to decode that before converting it to json.

Try this:

`initial_data = json.loads(file_content.decode('utf-8'))`